# Required CD/DVD device driver missing while installing WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation

I am trying to install Windows 7 and get this error:

> A required CD/DVD drive device driver
>   is missing. If you have a driver
>   floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash
>   drive, please insert it now.
>
> Note: If the Windows installation
>   media is in the CD/DVD drive, you can
>   safely remove it for this step.

It is booting off the dvd to get this far in the install. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it...

I had a DVD drive connected with an ide cable which was configured as master. The main hard disk was connected with a sata cable.

I changed the DVD drive from Master to Slave with the jumper setting and Windows installed with no more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I get this kind of messages problem is in error on installation media. If this is burned CD, I would check whether it was burned/downloaded correctly.