# A required cd/dvd drive device driver is missing when installing from pendrive

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, windows-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Required CD/DVD device driver missing while installing WIndows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/83228/required-cd-dvd-device-driver-missing-while-installing-windows-7)

I have a Thinkpad x120 with no OS preinstalled. When trying to install Windows 7 it shows the error "a required cd/dvd drive device driver is missing". Is there a separate driver i need to download for the Thinkpad?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Required CD/DVD device driver missing while installing WIndows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/83228/required-cd-dvd-device-driver-missing-while-installing-windows-7) and/or [Installing Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit mentions a missing CD/DVD driver?](http://superuser.com/questions/245368/installing-windows-7-ultimate-64-bit-mentions-a-missing-cd-dvd-driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same exact error while attempting to install Windows 8 RTM on my desktop from a Flash Drive...

Most of the time it means that the install file on your USB Drive is corrupted.

Try reformatting your flash drive and attempting another install:

Use the [Win7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool/3000-18513_4-10972600.html) to burn the ISO to the drive....there is also a helpful guide over at [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/business/2009/12/the-usb-flash-drive/)