# Windows 8 installation from USB flash drive

Tags: installation, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Required CD/DVD device driver missing while installing WIndows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/83228/required-CD-DVD-device-driver-missing-while-installing-Windows-7)

Trying to install Windows 8 64bit from a USB Flash drive and getting the error below. I used the Windows 7 USB Flash Tool to create the bootable USB Flash drive installer.

> A required CD/DVD device driver is missing. If you have a driver
>   floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive please insert it now. No
>   device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media
>   contains the correct drivers, then click ok.

Running Corsair 8GB Flash Voyager Drive on an Asus UL-20A Netbook.

Comment: This question is better suited to SuperUser. Hold on and it will be moved shortly, no need to repost. I seem to recall, however, if you unplug the USB and re-insert it into a *different* USB port setup installs the right driver and can continue. Hopefully SuperUser can confirm, though.

Comment: When exactly are you getting that error? I've installed Win8 off a USB drive and it works perfectly for me; though I used WinPE 3.0 for the booted OS.

Comment: I get that error during setup process, right after I click install button.

Comment: I tried to move the flash drive to another port after I got the error, didn't work at all.

Comment: That means the installer is not finding X:\sources\install.wim (where X: id the Flash drive). Please verify the file is there and is roughly 3.2GB.